# How to save data of two for loops in one array?

Tags: c#, xna

I have two for loops and I wanna save that data in one array. The first for loop will create 5 rectangles in the array. After that, the second for loop will create 5 rectangles and add them to the array. But something doesn't work. I get that "Index was outside the bounds of the array" error message in the last line of the code and I don't know what to change.

```
int framewidth = texture.Width / sourceRects.Length; 
int frameheight = texture.Height; 

private void vorrück(Rectangle[] sourceRects, int framewidth, int frameheight) 
    { 
        int doublelenght = sourceRects.Length * 2; 
        for (int i = 0; i < sourceRects.Length; i++) 
            sourceRects[i] = new Rectangle(i * framewidth, 0, framewidth, frameheight); 
        for (int normallenght = sourceRects.Length; normallenght < doublelenght; normallenght++) 
            sourceRects[normallenght] = new Rectangle((sourceRects.Length - 1 - normallenght) * framewidth, 0, framewidth, frameheight);      
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a bigger array.

The second loop very clearly writes outside the bounds, the relevant details are:

```
for (int normallenght = sourceRects.Length; ...; ...) 
        sourceRects[normallenght] = ...;  //  normallenght >= sourceRects.Length
```

As a general solution, do not use arrays so much. In this case a `List<Rectangle>` is probably the preferred datastructure.

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because the size of your Rectangle[] array is smaller than 10. Keep in mind that when you declare your Rectangle[] array, you should at least declare it with a size of 10.

```
Rectangle[] sourceRects = new Rectangle[10]; //(it will be from 0 to 9)
```

You will then be able to add 10 rectangles to it.

Answer (score 0):

You have made 2 mistakes (missing resize and second for never works).
Look at my modified code:

```
    private void vorrück(ref Rectangle[] sourceRects, int framewidth, int frameheight)
    {
        int doublelenght = sourceRects.Length * 2;     
        for (int i = 0; i < sourceRects.Length; i++)
        { 
            sourceRects[i] = new Rectangle(i * framewidth, 0, framewidth, frameheight);
        }
        Array.Resize(ref sourceRects, doublelenght); 
        for (int normallenght = sourceRects.Length /2; normallenght < doublelenght; normallenght++)
        {
            sourceRects[normallenght] = new Rectangle((sourceRects.Length - 1 - normallenght) * framewidth, 0, framewidth, frameheight);
        }
    }
```

This code will resize and fill your sourceRects array.

You can use this code like this:

```
        Rectangle[] sourceRects = new Rectangle[2];
        vorrück(ref sourceRects,5,4);
```